# li inside ul inside li

Tags: jquery, class, html-lists, inheritance

I'm using a menu which has this basic structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="index.php?location=home" id="home_link">HOME</a></li>
 <li id="movies_link_li"><a href="#" class="movies_link">MOVIES</a>
  <ul id="movies_submenu">
   <li><a href="#" id="insert_movie_link">Insert movie</a></li>   
   <li><a href="#" id="movie_images_link">Movie images</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="random_movie_link">Random movie</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

...and a css like this:

```
.current {background: #FFFFFF;}
```

I then use jquery and ajax to go to the different pages of my site, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

$(document).ready(function()
{       
    $(".movies_link").click(function(event){
        $("#conteudo").load("applet_movies.php",{'size':"fullscreen"});
        $('li').removeClass('current');$('#movies_link_li').addClass('current');
        $('#movie_images_link').removeClass('current');
        }); 
});
</script>
```

I am able to set the class "current" on the clicked menu item, but on IE (version 8) all the 'li' under the clicked 'li' inherit the same class, which messes up the menu. None of the other browsers are doing this.

Is there any way to stop IE from setting the 'current' class to all the 'li' under the clicked 'li'?

I just tried these other methods, but none worked:

```
$(".movies_link").click(function(event){
        $("#conteudo").load("applet_movies.php",{'size':"fullscreen"});
        $('li').removeClass('current');
        $('#movies_link_li').addClass('current');
        $('#movie_images_link').removeClass(); //jquery remove all classes from element, didn't work.
        $('#movies_link_li').children().removeClass('current'); //nothing...
        $('#random_movie_link').removeClass('current'); //also nothing...
        $('#movie_images_link').addClass('normalmenuitem'); //explicitly set another class / override - also nothing happened! :(
});
```

Comment: It's an <a> tag in disguise. Otherwise spam protection wouldn't le me post my question! :)

Comment: @Pipanni: You /can/ post HTML here, you need to put it inside code blocks.  Press `Ctrl+k` or press the `{}` button.

Comment: @Pipanni I changed them back to a-tags for you. If you ever need to do that, use a null-character between the `<` and the `a` and it'll be fine I guess.

Comment: @Radek: Or put it in code tags.

Comment: @Rocket won't work. However, indentation with four spaces, or using backticks will. Ordinary code tags won't.

Comment: @Radek: My bad, I meant code *blocks*, `Ctrl+k` or the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to your `click` handler.

```
$(".movies_link").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but IE still applies the class to all the 'li' child links. I'm gonna try a few other things and I'll be back tomorrow.